# Installing a catkin package without work space

Tags: ros, installation, catkin, rosrun

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To my understanding, catkin provides 2 different functionalities:

1. a way to handle dependencies between packages in the installation process and
2. a tool to create ROS services and messages.

As I am already using appropriate tools for 1, I wish to use catkin only for 2.
In other words, I use catkin macros
`add_message_files`,
`add_service_files`
to generate the source code relative to my services and topics, but I want to install my package in the standard way:

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=myprefix -DCMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR=myprefix/lib..
make install
```

I use `CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION` cmake macro as defined by REP 122 to install package relative executable and scripts.

As expected, cmake installs my executables in `myprefix/lib/pkg-name` with execution rights for everyone.

However, when I type `rosrun pkg-name executable`, i.e. `rosrun dynamic_graph_bridge run_command`
I get the following message:

```
[rosrun] Couldn't find executable named run_command below /home/florent/devel/ros/install/share/dynamic_graph_bridge
```

when as explained before run_command is in `/home/florent/devel/ros/install/lib/dynamic_graph_bridge`.

my ROS_PACKAGE_PATH contains `/home/florent/devel/ros/install:/opt/ros/groovy/share:/opt/ros/groovy/stacks`

What did I wrong?
Why does the error message seem inconsistent with REP 122?

I run groovy on ubuntu-12.04 32bits.
The package can be found at http://www.github.com/stack-of-tasks/dynamic_graph_bridge.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/107036/installing-a-catkin-package-without-work-space/) by [florent-lamiraux](https://answers.ros.org/users/5734/florent-lamiraux/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2013-12-04

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mikepurvis](https://answers.ros.org/users/270/mikepurvis/) on 2013-12-05**:
Catkin itself actually doesn't provide the macros for message and service creation—it provides the mechanism by which those other packages may inject CMake functions in at the find_package point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH` is not sufficient to find scripts in a workspace with FHS layout.

The setup files in a catkin workspace are also defining the CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH which lists  all workspace root folders. And those folders contain an empty `.catkin` marker file. `rosrun` uses these paths to identify locations where executables may be located.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2013-12-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Catkin also manages the workspace setup file. Are you opposed to using the provided workspace setup?

```
source /home/florent/devel/ros/install/setup.bash
rosrun dynamic_graph_bridge run_command
```

Also, for more insight into what's going on, try checking the output of `catkin_find` as well.

---

Originally posted by [mikepurvis](https://answers.ros.org/users/270/mikepurvis/) with karma: 1153 on 2013-12-05

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [florent-lamiraux](https://answers.ros.org/users/5734/florent-lamiraux/) on 2013-12-05**:
Thank you for your answer. I tried to source `/home/florent/devel/ros/install/setup.bash` without modifying any ROS_ environment variable and I get the following environment:

```
student@student-virtualbox:~$ env | grep ROS
ROS_ROOT=/opt/ros/groovy/share/ros
ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/home/student/devel/sot/install/share:/home/student/devel/sot/install/stacks:/opt/ros/groovy/share:/opt/ros/groovy/stacks
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311
ROSLISP_PACKAGE_DIRECTORIES=
ROS_DISTRO=groovy
ROS_ETC_DIR=/opt/ros/groovy/etc/ros
```

Unfortunately, `/home/student/devel/sot/install/lib` is not in `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH` and rosrun dynamic_graph_bridge run_command still fails.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-12-05**:
It is nearly impossible to read your comment above. If you edited your question to format that information, it would be easier to help. A common cause of failures like this is having failed to source the ROS distro setup properly *before* creating the workspace. People often skip that step.

**Comment by [mikepurvis](https://answers.ros.org/users/270/mikepurvis/) on 2013-12-05**:
Hmm, not sure what else to suggest. Maybe first check that you can build the package as usual with `catkin_make` before attempting this alternative approach? Consider also updating your question with clarification about what it is you're trying to avoid and why; there may be an easier way.